# Why can I not call a protected constructor from a subclass?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm in the process of converting a VB.NET project to C#. There's a block of code that when converted, has a method which calls a protected constructor in a superclass. I've made a minimum example here:

```cs
public class A
{
    protected A() { }
}

public class B : A
{
    static A MakeA() {
        return new A();
    }
}
```

On the `new A()` I am getting "CS0122: A.A() is inaccessible due to its protection level".

Now the reason this is an issue for me is that class `A` is in a library that I cannot control. Our VB.NET code was having no problem calling this constructor, but C# is.

Why is this a thing?

What can I do about it?

Comment: You can not access `A`s other than those which __actually__ are part of a `B` instance.

Comment: `Our VB.NET code was having no problem calling this constructor, but C# is` - implement `Shared MakeA() As A` in VB?

Comment: The deeper question here is: if the author of `A` does not want `A` instantiated directly (thus having only a protected constructor), why would you want/be allowed to do this to begin with? The fact that VB allows this is a bit baffling to be honest, it shouldn`t.

Comment: @InBetween I'm also surprised VB lets us do that, although I don't understand what good protected constructors are if subclasses cannot call them. I didn't write the VB so I'm trying to avoid changing our implementation, though I think that's the way I will have to go.

Comment: protected constructors can be called by the constructor of the derived class as in `public B() : base("pass any required parameters here") { }`.

Comment: Of course protected base class constructors can be called; you would not be able to create an instance of `B` if no constructors of `A` were accesible. But there are rules on where and when you are allowed to call them. Try inheriting from a class that has only private constructors and see what happens.

Comment: I think it's a bug in the VB compiler to let this through, as the language specification uses similar verbiage to C#.

Comment: Specifically, "A Protected member is accessible to a derived class, provided that either the member is not an instance member, or the access takes place through an instance of the derived class."  In this case, the member is an instance member, and the access is not taking place through an instance of the derived class.  Quoted from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/general-concepts

Comment: FYI I submitted issue 67130 for the VB compiler.

Comment: Quick update on my last: the issue was closed as won't-fix because the behavior goes back to the original native VB.NET compiler, and it was judged to be a significant breaking change.

Answer (score 4):

This is called out in [the C# spec (ECMA-334)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#754-protected-access), with a reason given *(my bold)*

> **7.5.4 Protected access**
>
> When a `protected` or `private protected` instance member is accessed outside the program text of the class in which it is declared, and when a `protected internal` instance member is accessed outside the program text of the program in which it is declared, the access shall take place within a class declaration that derives from the class in which it is declared. **Furthermore, the access is required to take place through an instance of that derived class type or a class type constructed from it.** This restriction prevents one derived class from accessing protected members of other derived classes, even when the members are inherited from the same base class.

While it doesn't make a huge difference with constructors, it affects regular methods a lot. For example, you wouldn't want this to happen

```cs
public abstract class Animal
{
    protected abstract void DoThing();
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    protected override void DoThing() => WagTail();

    private void WagTail()
    {
        // Whatever
    }
}

public class EvilCat : Animal
{
    public static void WagDogsTail(Dog dog) => dog.DoThing();

    public static void MeowCat(EvilCat cat) => cat.DoThing();

    protected override void DoThing() => Meow();

    private void Meow()
    {
        // Whatever
    }
}
```

You *must* use an instance of *your own* type to do it, so `MeowCat` would be allowed, but not `WagDogsTail`. A constructor therefore can only be called via an instance of your own derived class, so you cannot call it directly using `new()`, only using `base()` from another constructor.

---

It's also mentioned in [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_5th_edition_december_2010.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A78%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C69%2C527%2C0%5D), the spec for .NET:

> **8.5.3.2 Accessibility of members and nested types**
>
> **family** – accessible to referents that support the same type (i.e., an exact type and all of the types that inherit from it). For verifiable code (see §8.8), there is an additional requirement that can require
> a runtime check: **the reference shall be made through an item whose exact type supports the exact type of the referent.** That is, the item whose member is being accessed shall inherit from the type performing the access.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to understand why the base class is using a protected constructor. It will probably supply some kind of factory method to create an instance of the base class, and you should be using that.

It's possible to subvert this somewhat in the derived class by simply returning an instance of the derived class:

```
public class B : A
{
    public static A MakeA()
    {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

This is likely a VERY BAD IDEA.

Imagine if the implementation of `A` relies on some special code that initialises some of the fields of `A` after the protected constructor has completed, such as:

```
public class A
{
    public static A Create()
    {
        return new A
        {
            _mustBeInitialised = 42
        };
    }

    protected A() {}

    public int Func(int value)
    {
        return value / _mustBeInitialised;
    }

    int _mustBeInitialised;
}
```

With those two classes, code would be able to do this:

```
A a = B.MakeA();
Console.WriteLine(a.Func(10));
```

with horrible results.

So you must find out how an instance of `A` is correctly created and use that instead.

Comment: But on the other hand you can generate such a "horrible result" by simply returning `new B()`, as the `Create` function stll won't be called. I've thought about this and can't come up with a case when there would be a subversion of encapsulation, I think the only reason for the restriction is to match protected methods and properties, when obviously encapsulation would be an issue.